# How to create a menu on every frame of a Tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm aware of how to create a basic Tkinter menu bar, but I'm not sure how to implement it such that the menu appears on every frame of a multi-frame GUI.

I will be using the menu bar to switch between frames. Therefore, I need to run the `controller.show_frame` command within the menu commands. I am currently using buttons to do this.

I'm unable to find a way to do this, as (as far as I am aware) the menu must be created in the frame class rather than the `tk.Tk` class, in order to allow me to run the function.

Here is the code:

```
""" Messing about with tkinter """
import tkinter as tk
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

class Window(tk.Tk):
    """ Main class """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for frame in (Main, Checker):
            current_frame = frame(container, self)
            self.frames[frame] = current_frame
            current_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Main)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        """ Raises a particular frame, bringing it into view """

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

def qprint(quick_print):
    """ Function to print a string """
    print(quick_print)

class Main(tk.Frame):
    """ Main frame of program """

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Main Menu", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

class Checker(tk.Frame):
    """ Password Strength Checker """

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Password Checker", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


APP = Window()
APP.geometry("350x200")
APP.mainloop()
```

Comment: Better to have a single outer Toplevel or Frame with the Menu, and just change the inner Frame.

Comment: _"the menu must be created in the frame class rather than the tk.Tk class, in order to allow me to run the function."_ - that is not a true statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"the menu must be created in the frame class rather than the tk.Tk class, in order to allow me to run the
>   function."*

I don't think that's true, see below example that creates `Menu` for a `Toplevel` widget:

```
import tkinter as tk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    toplevel = tk.Toplevel(root)

    # create a toplevel menu
    menubar = tk.Menu(toplevel)
    menubar.add_command(label="Hello!")
    menubar.add_command(label="Quit!", command=root.quit)

    # display the menu
    toplevel.config(menu=menubar)

    root.mainloop()
```

---

Alternatively, you can create menu's in frames *for* their parents with the condition that their parent is `Toplevel`-like.

In below example when a menu item is selected `Root`'s menu jumps between the `Root`'s menu and its children `FrameWithMenu` object's menu:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("The Root class with menu")
        self.a_frame = FrameWithMenu(self)
        self.create_menu()

    def create_menu(self):
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Root", command=self.a_frame.replace_menu)
        self['menu'] = self.menubar



class FrameWithMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

    def replace_menu(self):
        """ Overwrite parent's menu if parent's class name is in _valid_cls_names.
        """

        _parent_cls_name = type(self.master).__name__
        _valid_cls_names = ("Tk", "Toplevel", "Root")
        if _parent_cls_name in _valid_cls_names:
            self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
            self.menubar.add_command(label="Frame", command=self.master.create_menu)
            self.master['menu'] = self.menubar


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!menu"`. The line in question: `self.menubar.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.quit())`. `quit` simply executes `self.destroy()`.

Comment: @Bravewave Make sure to exclude `()` from `command` keyword-argument as in `..., command=self.quit)`.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my own question. All I needed to do was create the menu using the `controller` parameter, which references the `tk.Tk` class.

```
class Main(tk.Frame):
    """ Main frame of program """

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Main Menu", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        menubar = tk.Menu(controller)
        menubar.add_command(label="Checker", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Checker))
        controller.config(menu=menubar)
```